# IIS7 Website Resource Management

Tags: iis-7, resources, web

How to limit resources (RAM and Space) for a website hosted on IIS7 platform?

Comment: I think you are talking about `cache size limit`. Take a look here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772095(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thru the GUI, you can set them under `Application Pools > [AppPool] > Advanced Settings - Recycling`

Thru command line:

```
appcmd set config /section:applicationPools /[name=' string '].recycling.periodicRestart.privateMemory: uint
```